# Stop foreach and return to the array that was stopped

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I am trying to creat an CSV file for each array(111, arm_2, trye) inside the $StockReady array.

```
$StockReady
Array
(
    [111] => Array()
    [arm_2] => Array()
    [trye] => Array()
)
```

I have this:

```
        $CurrentArmazem = $StockReady;
        reset($CurrentArmazem);
        $CurrentArmazem = key($CurrentArmazem);

         foreach ($StockReady as $CodArmazem => $line) {

             $FileName = $CodArmazem . '.csv';

             if ($CurrentArmazem === $CodArmazem) {

                 foreach ($line as $value) {
                     $Stocks .= $value[0];
                 }

                 $doc = $dir . $FileName;
                 $myfile = fopen($doc, "w");
                 fwrite($myfile, $Stocks . "\n");
                 fclose($myfile);
             }else{
                 $CurrentArmazem = $CodArmazem;
         }
     }
```

So this runs good for the first time because $currentarmazem is set 'manually' but when it goes to the next array it wont work because `if ($CurrentArmazem === $CodArmazem)` is not true anymore, it instead incorrectly goes into the `else` and does not re-run that array. Is there anything I can put inside the `else` so it returns to the array it missed?

Comment: why you need this if/else anyway? do you have a whitelist/blacklist of stuff you want to exclude based on array key?

Comment: when the array key changes it must creat a csv file. So for each array key i need a file with with array content

Comment: Then just remove the if else. i will post an answer to it explaining.

Comment: of course i did that already, the problem is that all 3 files will have each other values.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do. You have 3 nested arrays each of them with different keys. You want to create 3 csv files with the keyname of each nested array. Right?

Comment: nop. create 3 files from the 3 arrays, each file must only contain its values, the problem is that if i take out the 'if' the 3 files will contain all values from arrays

Comment: I see now. wait i edit my answer.

Comment: Try my code. I made a small change while you were assigning a value in `$Stocks` variable so please copy and paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

It doesn't actually look like you need the if/else, the key will change on each loop, I'm also not sure why you're resetting the array when nothing has been changed.

In addition to this, I am now resetting the $Stocks variable on each iteration, so the following loop should not contain any of the previous loops data.

**Try replacing your code with the below:**

```
foreach ($StockReady as $CodArmazem => $line) {

    $Stocks = '';

    $FileName = $CodArmazem . '.csv';

    foreach ($line as $value) $Stocks .= $value[0];

    $doc = $dir . $FileName;
    $myfile = fopen($doc, "w");
    fwrite($myfile, $Stocks . "\n");
    fclose($myfile);

}
```

Comment: I need, because it will pass the values of each array into each other. Of course i did that already lol. Thanks for the fast awnser

Comment: Oh, you just need to reset the $Stocks string then, I'll edit now.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($StockReady as $CodArmazem => $line) {
    $FileName = $CodArmazem . '.csv';

    foreach ($line as $value) {
        $Stocks = $value[0];
    }
    $doc = $dir . $FileName;
    $myfile = fopen($doc, "w");
    fwrite($myfile, $Stocks . "\n");
    fclose($myfile);
}
```

You can simple remove your if/else statement and have it work. You will create the file based on your `key` value because you assign a value to your `$FileName` variable based on your array key, in every loop.

Edited my code based on your comment so your `$Stocks` variable will be reassigned with a new value for every loop.

Based on your code you were concatenating data to the same variable so you ended up with all the data from all the arrays to be stored in this variable cause of wrong concatenation.

Comment: This isn't what he wants to do, the $Stocks variable will only ever equal the first piece of information in the array, he could have an array of information, the correct route would be to reset the $Stocks string at the start of the loop and continue to build it up as he was doing before.

Comment: Wans't me on the devote, i used the Mark's code, i havent tested yours but i think it will do the same. Thanks alot for the  help.

Comment: @Mark Overton According to OP question the nested arrays don't have more nested arrays but fields so that's why i did not take this under consideration in my answer. But you are right that in case there are nested arrays in there your solution will work also for that, it's a more general solution.